# Migrating from OWIN to ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, owin, katana

When moving from OWIN to ASP.NET Core, I've found a bit of [information about dependencies to migration](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=roadmap&referringTitle=Home), but I've not found information about these other topics:

- The middle-ware pipeline.  How is this different, or not?
- The DelegatingHandler pipeline (e.g. Web API).  How is this different, or not?
- The startup.cs file.  How is this different?

In short, it would be great to know what are the primary hot-spots that would need my attention, in order to move from OWIN to ASP.NET Core.

As a first example - ASP.NET Core does not appear to have `HttpConfiguration`.  There are myriads of example plugins and services that assume its existence.  I'd like to *infer* how to translate instructions for `HttpConfiguration` into whatever approach ASP.NET Core expects.

As another example, the [Swashbuckle documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) gives instructions for setup with OWIN, but those instructions don't work with ASP.NET Core.  If I understood the primary differences from OWIN, it would be easier to "guesstimate" how to install Swashbuckle into ASP.NET Core.

- Note: Swashbuckle also gives instructions for `self-hosted` apps. That confuses me because I think of OWIN (*vis-a-vis* Katana) as being self-hosted already, and so it sounds redundant to me.  But I don't think this is related to the present question.

My question has used Swashbuckle as an example, but I am not asking about Swashbuckle specifically.

### Update

I've discovered that much of the information I'm looking for is in the article [Transitioning from Web API 2 to ASP.NET MVC 6](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1149/convert-aspnet-webapi2-aspnet5-mvc6).

Answer (score 26):

- Middleware is quite similar between Katana and Core but you use HttpContext instead of IOwinContext.
- Startup.cs is similar but there's much more DI support.
- WebApi has been merged into MVC
- DelegatingHandler is gone, use middleware instead.
- HttpConfiguration has been split up into Routing and MvcOptions.

Also https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/katana-asp-net-5-and-bridging-the-gap/

Comment: I'm assuming the link is practically useless, since it was written in 2014.  Much has changed since then.  Thoughts?

Comment: There have been name changes that broke some of the links, but the concepts discussed are still valid.

Answer (score 10):

I think you can start [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/owin.html). It's an entire chapter about OWIN with ASP.NET Core. Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this help? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/11/14/katana-asp-net-5-and-bridging-the-gap/